# What do these subprograms do?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, python-3.5

I'm practising Python - using Python 3.5.0 - I came across this brief program using subprograms. I'm trying to figure out what each subprogram does?

Thank you very much in advance.

```
def A(target,mark)
    target=mark[0]
    for numbers in range(10):
        if mark[numbers] > target:
    target = mark[numbers]
    return target


def B (target, mark)
    target=mark[0]
    for numbers in range(10):
        if mark[numbers] < target:
            target = mark[numbers]
    return target


def C (vote,total,vote1,vote0)
    for noofvotes in range(total):
    if vote[noofvotes]==1:
    vote1=vote1 + 1
        else:
    vote0=vote0 + 1
    return vote0, vote1


def D(target,Name):
    found="NO"
    namesinarray=0
    while namesinarray != len(Name) and found == "NO":
        if Name[namesinarray]==target:
            found="YES"
            indexmark= namesinarray
        namesinarray = namesinarray +1

    if found=="YES":
        print(target + " has been found at position " + str(indexmark))
    else:
        print("This name is not in the list")
```

Comment: Don't know who wrote this code but it's horrible.  This being said, you'd still should be able to find out what each of these functions do by yourself. Hint: if just reading and reasonning about the code isn't enough,  Python has both an interactive interpreter and a step debugger (that you can launch from the interactive interpreter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`A()` searches through each of the first 10 elements of `mark`, and keeps updating `target` if that element is greater than `target`.  The result is, it returns the greatest element of `mark`.  `B()` is similar, but it returns the smallest element of `mark`.  These are not needed, however, because there are builtin functions called `max()` and `min()` that were made for just that.  `C()` receives for its arguments a list of votes, the total number of votes given, the number of votes that so far have been for one person, and the number of votes that so far have been for another person.  It goes through the votes and checks to see if it is 0 or 1.  It then updates the vote counts accordingly.  Once it has added all the votes, it returns them in a `tuple`.  (That is, that's what it would do if it were indented correctly).  `D()` is given `target` and `Name` for its arguments, and it searches through `Name` until it finds `target`.  If `target` is found, it prints that the target has been found at a certain position.  If it is not found, it prints `This name is not in the list`.  This function could be improved, because it uses `"YES"` and `"NO"` for its booleans.  Booleans were built into the Python language, and therefore should be used.  It could also use the builtin method `index()` like this:

```
def D(target, Name):
    try:
        index = Name.index(target)
    except IndexError:
        print("This name is not in the list")
    else:
        print(target + " has been found at position " + str(index))
```